# PipelineModuleStepContainer.GetEventCount fails once or twice per day

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

One or twice per day, I get the following error in the Windows Event Log. After it comes, my web application no longer serves any requests, each time there is a request, this error will be logged again.

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.PipelineModuleStepContainer.GetEventCount(RequestNotification notification, Boolean isPostEvent)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
```

I have found other mentions of this error, but one of them is a case where it happens consistently, so that does not apply to my scenario. And another is mentioned in the context of a specific application and says nothing in general about why this error appears or how to debug it.

I need some help to debug this error and find out what the real error is. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you running NewRelic?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and we were running New Relic. Removing the agent seemed to fix it.

Comment: That must have been it because, yes, I was running New Relic at the time.